# How to create a temporary variable equal to the id of the last inserted row

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

SQL n00b here. Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Hopefully you can figure out what I'm intending to to.

```
DECLARE @CatId INT;
SET @CatId = (
    INSERT INTO Categories (CategoryName) VALUES ('TestCategory');
    SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
);
INSERT INTO Fields (CategoryID,FieldName,DisplayName) VALUES (@CatId,'TestName','TestDisplayName');
```

I'm getting the not-very-detailed error

> Incorrect syntax near 'INSERT'

Comment: there's no `IMPORT` in your query

Comment: You can't set a variable like that.

Comment: use OUTPUT inserted into a temp table or table variable, especially if your set operation will be more than 1 record.

Comment: You could have used a scalar `select` subquery to set a variable. But you can't use an insert which is what @Sean Lange is saying.

Answer (score 3):

In SQL Server, the right way to handle this is the `OUTPUT` clause.  I would recommend that you learn this method and stick to it.

```
DECLARE @CatIds TABLE (catid int);

INSERT INTO Categories (CategoryName)
    OUTPUT inserted.catid INTO @CatIds;
    VALUES ('TestCategory');

INSERT INTO Fields(CategoryID, FieldName, DisplayName) 
    SELECT CatId, 'TestName', 'TestDisplayName'
    FROM @CatIds;
```

This is preferable to other methods because it *explicitly* captures the desired information into a table, which can then be further processed.  Code is more robust because there is no danger of adding a line of code "in between" and breaking the existing code.  It also supports inserts of multiple values at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need a variable for this. Remember the KISS principal.

```
INSERT INTO Categories (CategoryName) VALUES ('TestCategory');
INSERT INTO Fields (CategoryID,FieldName,DisplayName) VALUES (SCOPE_IDENTITY(),'TestName','TestDisplayName');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`IDENT_CURRENT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms175098.aspx)

```
DECLARE @CatId INT   
SELECT @CatId = IDENT_CURRENT('Categories')
```

Then reuse the `@CatId` in the `INSERT`

```
INSERT INTO Fields (CategoryID, FieldName, DisplayName) VALUES (@CatId,'TestName','TestDisplayName');
```

`IDENT_CURRENT` returns the last identity value generated for a specific table in any session and any scope.

If you need it to be only scoped to your session you can use [`SCOPE_IDENTITY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms190315.aspx)

Comment: This has potential concurrency issues.

Comment: @SeanLange if multiple sessions are a problem, the OP can use `SCOPE_IDENTITY`

Comment: Your code should ALWAYS be able to handle multiple sessions. When you use IDENT_CURRENT like this you are creating a race condition. Why use something that has the potential to be a problem? Just use SCOPE_IDENTITY and you don't have to qualify it.

Comment: @SeanLange - if it `ALWAYS` needs to handle multiple scope/sessions, `SCOPE_IDENTITY` doesnt.  From the docs: `SCOPE_IDENTITY and @@IDENTITY return the last identity values that are generated in any table in the current session. However, SCOPE_IDENTITY returns values inserted only within the current scope; @@IDENTITY is not limited to a specific scope.` - Both functions have their place.

Comment: That is correct. And in my experience there has not yet ever been a case where @@IDENTITY was a good choice. It would be useful if there was a trigger that inserted into another table and you wanted the identity from that insert. For the OP's question, IDENT_CURRENT is simply not the right tool for the job. It is a perfectly fine tool but not when it generates a race condition when it can be avoided.

Comment: @SeanLange - of course it's correct, it's from the documentation.

Comment: That's hilarious!!! The documentation cannot be just accepted blindly. There are so many inconsistencies it isn't even funny. There are many things in the official documentation that just are not correct. I don't fault MS for this, the documentation is massive and has been growing and changing for many years.